# Estou tentando fazer upload de um arquivo com ajax mas não estou conseguindo: "Undefined index: arquivo in"

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

Formulário:

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="arquivo" multiple/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="linkTest" value="Consultar">
</form>
```

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#linkTest").on('click', function(e){     
    e.preventDefault();
        var form = $('form')[0];
        var formData = new FormData(form);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: 'formData',
            proccessData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];
?>
```

Comment: Sugestão: troque o evento do botão para o evento de submit do form. Isso TB vai facilitar para pegar os dados e fazer o envio.

Comment: Vc está fazendo o envio de uma string e não do objeto formData. Retire as aspas de data: 'formData'

Comment: TB há [esse exemplo](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.cloudways.com/blog/the-basics-of-file-upload-in-php/amp/), que é exatamente o que vc quer fazer.

Comment: Tirei as aspas e agr n recebo mais resposta nenhuma. Vou olhar esse artigo q me mostrou

Comment: O problema tava em "proccessData: false," o certo seria: "processData: false,"

Comment: E funciona mesmo com o form data como string?

Comment: Neste caso, adicione uma resposta e marque a mesma como aceita. Destaque o problema no erro de digitação.

Comment: E a pergunta deverá ser fechada, por ser somente um erro de digitação.

Comment: Não!  só depois de corrigir a aspas e aí sim corrigir o "proccessData: false," para "processData: false,".

Answer (score 0):

Erro de digitação em:

```
 data: 'formData',
```

para:

```
data: formData,
```

e em:

```
proccessData: false,
```

para:

```
processData: false,
```